# have can i retrive my bcc (bitcoin cash) from bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

bittrex says i set bitcoin cash (bcc) to a bitcoin address ..i had made numerous trans actions before using bcc bitcoin cash ,,as i was transfereing i saw the screen change and so did the deposit address to the bitcoin address ..when i contacted bittrex they said it was my fault and said they couldnt do anything and said it was a matter to go to cross chain recovery ...i cant find anything to contact them ..can any help

Comment: there are several threads concerning bcc and bitcoin mix, e.g here: /questions/62456/accidentally-sent-bitcoin-cash-to-bitcoin-address-held-by-a-third-party and here: /questions/57419/what-would-happen-if-you-send-bitcoin-btc-to-a-bitcoin-cash-bch-aka-bcc-add. There is more in the forum, hopefully this helps. forum here has no possibility to help with BitTRex issues, the question might get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. Do you control the adress you sent the bitcoin to? If so, simply import the private key in a wallet compatible with bitcoin cash.

If you don't, you're dependant on bittrex, and they only recover amounts higher as 5000$, with a 10% fee i think.

https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000961172-Bittrex-s-Crosschain-Recovery-Policy